# Restricting on yesterday from a specific time

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports

Using Crystal Reports 13.

I have created a combined date and time field and called it

```
 @admin
datetime({x_med_admins.admin_date},{x_med_admins.admin_time})
```

I now want to use this @admin to pull records from yesterday from 2pm up until today at 10am.

I cannot seem to find the best way to do this. I can do it putting in yesterday as a specific date but that is no good going forward as I will need it to run each day automatically. I was trying to use currentdatetime -1 in conjunction with @admin but no luck.

Thanks
Ian

Comment: I have now done {@admin} < currentdatetime and{@admin} > DateAdd ("h",-20,currentdatetime)    . However this relies on the report working bang on time at 10am each day which it wont always due to delays with other reports. Still need to somehow specify from 2pm yesterday to 10am today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this:

```
     {@admin} < currentdatetime and{@admin} >CDateTime(year(currentdatetime), 
month(currentdatetime), day(currentdatetime), 10,00, 00)
```

Comment: I must be looking in the wrong place. Where do I accept it as answered?